Facebook login flow: Unable to publish the app
I have a website, and I have implemented and tested Facebook login flow. Then I have released the website, provided all required information to publish the facebook app. I went to the next step of Business Verification and went to 'Create a Business Manager account', when I click Create, I receive
Sorry, this feature isn't available right now
An error occurred while processing this request. Please try again later.

It's been a few days, nothing changed. Can I be doing something wrong?
